# insert <br> after point jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How to insert tag 
 after first point in text?

For example I have

```
<p>Some text here. Some text after point.</p>
```

result

```
<p>Some text here.<br> Some text after point.</p>
```

Comment: Is there always only at max two points???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read text of `p` element then use `replace` to add `br` element and put whole text in html of `p` tag.

```js
$(function(){
var text = $('p').text();
    text = text.replace('here.','here.<br>');
    $('p').html(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Some text here. Some text after point.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expression.

```
"<p>Some text here.  Some text after point.</p>".replace(/(\.\s+)/g, "$1<br/>")
```

this will give you the following output

```
"<p>Some text here.  <br/>Some text after point.</p>"
```